# SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper is not a function custom html page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a custom peoplepicker on a custom html page that was converted to an aspx page. I'm using SharePoint Online. I'm getting the error:
SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper is not a function

I'm going off of this documentation: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/client-side-people-picker-in-sharepoint-2013, but not loading the JS files. I don't know if I am missing any SP tags that need to be added to get it to work.

Below is what I have in the top of my page. What am I missing to get it to work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %> <%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint"
namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint,
Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html
  xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
>
  <head>
    <title>Personnel Reporting Tool</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../SiteAssets/testingAubrey/css/testingAubrey.css"
    />
    <link
      id="favicon"
      href="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=47"
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    />

    <!--[if gte mso 9
      ]><xml>
        <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
          <mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string"
            >QFZ5RRHKX53H-471360874-8</mso:_dlc_DocId
          >
          <mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string"
            >e5733fa7-6078-43c6-89a6-d5124a2d3cef</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid
          >
          <mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string"
            >https://usdos.sharepoint.com/sites/DS-PSS/timesheet/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=QFZ5RRHKX53H-471360874-8,
            QFZ5RRHKX53H-471360874-8</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl
          >
        </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
      </xml><!
    [endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <SharePoint:FormDigest
        ID="FormDigest1"
        runat="server"
      ></SharePoint:FormDigest>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@A.h. Laverty,

Please take a reference of below aspx code:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html dir="ltr">

<head runat="server">
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css"/>
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="microsoftajax.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />  
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />    
    
    <style type="text/css">
        .sp-peoplepicker-topLevel{
            height:auto !important;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>

    <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
    <div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Get User Info" onclick="getUserInfo()"></input>
        <br/>
        <h1>User info:</h1>
        <p id="resolvedUsers"></p>
        <h1>User keys:</h1>
        <p id="userKeys"></p> 
        <h1>User ID:</h1>
        <p id="userId"></p>
    </div>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" id="FormDigest1"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Run your custom code when the DOM is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the
    // picker will render.
    initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
});

// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

// Query the picker for user information.
function getUserInfo() {

    // Get the people picker object from the page.
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

    // Get information about all users.
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var userInfo = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        for (var userProperty in user) { 
            userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
        }
    }
    $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

    // Get user keys.
    var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
    $('#userKeys').html(keys);

    // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.
    getUserId(users[0].Key);
}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), 
         Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );
}

function ensureUserSuccess() {
    $('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}



</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Test Result:

[image]

More reference:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in#code-example-using-the-client-side-people-picker-in-a-sharepoint-hosted-add-in

BR